# Implement a filter which in case of null return all the data

Tags: java, filter

How to implement a filter which in case of null returns all the data?
For example if name is null it should be excluded from the filter.
The only way in my head is to make 100k lines of code and test all of the combinations. It is very stupid. I dont want it like this. I am sure there is better way.

```
Collection<Ojects> filter(String name, Integer age, Integer number) ;
```

Comment: What you you mean `in case of null`? What would be null? What data are you returning?

Comment: at least you could copy all you homework here so we understand what it is!!

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: your line of code is not correct:

To call the filter method:

```
Collection<Ojects> ojects = filter(String name, Integer age, Integer number);
```

Also there are a lot of details missing in your question, but to use as a guide: check if all the conditions to filter are null and return all elements else do the filter:

```
public Collection<Ojects> filter(String name, Integer age, Integer number) {
    // return all object if no filter
    if (name == null && age == null && number == null) {
        Collection<Ojects> allOjects = // get all objects from where you wish
        return allOjects;
    }

    // do the filters
    Collection<Ojects> filteredOjects = new ....

    // filter by name
    if (name != null && name.lenght > 0) {
        // do the filter and put the matching ones in filtered objects
    }

    // filter by age
    if (age != null && age < 0) {
        // do the filter and put the matching ones in filtered objects
    }

    // filter by number
    if (name != null // conditions you need) {
        // do the filter and put the matching ones in filtered objects
    }


    return filteredObjects
}
```

If you don't filter when parameters are not given you will return all objects...

Comment: and if  I have 10 parameters. What I am going to do 1 milion lines of code ?

Comment: as long as you don't provide much info, **YES**... there are plenty of ways to reduce the code, but according your specs (thats, nothing) this is the best you can do